# warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size

Tags: gcc, int, void-pointers, gcc-warning

I'm working on socket programming.. my code executes the way I want it to, I'm able to use it. BUT it gives me a warning on compilation.

I compile using

```
gcc server1.c -o server1 -lpthread
```

And I get the warning

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

This error comes for the following code

```
int newsockfd;
newsockfd = (int)newsockfdd; //this line
```

And I'm using newsockfdd (which is int) in the following chunk of code

```
if (pthread_create(&threadID[i++], NULL, serverThread, (void *)(intptr_t)newsockfdd) != 0)
    {
        perror("Thread create error");
    }
```

As you can probably tell, the code is not written too well (I am working on making it better). I know that this warning comes because of something to do with the size of int. But I really dunno how to fix it. Before I put in (intptr_t) in the pthread_create statement, it was showing a warning on that line, but that time the warning was

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

It seems like there should be a simple fix to this? But I can't find it. I'm using Ubuntu 64-bit. Is that a reason for the warning?

Comment: Hmm, given the warning you got from `(void*)newsockfdd` before you interposed the cast to `intptr_t`, it seems unlikely that the `cast from pointer to integer of different size` warning is actually from the indicated line.

Comment: Unless... Is that line in `serverThread` and `newsockfdd` is the argument that `serverThread` receives? Then it would be clear.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes.. I pass it as an argument to serverThread. Like so: void *serverThread(void *newsockfdd). So what is wrong?

Comment: Well, the function you're running as a `pthread` takes a `void*` as argument. So your `int` is first cast to `void*` when it is passed, then in `serverThread`, the `void*` is cast back to `int`. It's bad style, bad probably will work. But, if possible, pass a _pointer_ to `newsockfdd` and in `serverThread`, cast that pointer to `int*` and dereference it.

Answer (score 6):

As has been established in the comments, the situation is (modulo renaming to avoid confusing occurrences of `newsockfdd` as passed argument or received parameter)

```
void *serverThread(void *arg) {
    // ...
    int newsockfd = (int)arg;
    // ...
}
```

and in `main` (or a function called from there)

```
// ...
int newsockfdd = whatever;
// ...
if (pthread_create(&threadID[i++], NULL, serverThread, (void *)(intptr_t)newsockfdd) != 0)
// ..
```

So when the `int newsockfdd` is passed as an argument to `serverThread`, it is cast to a `void*`. Originally, that cast was direct, but the intermediate cast to `intptr_t` was inserted to remove the warning about the `cast to pointer from integer of different size`.

And in `serverThread`, the received `void*` is cast to `int`, resulting in the warning about the `cast from pointer to integer of different size`.

That warning could probably also be removed by inserting an intermediate cast to `intptr_t`.

But, while the standard allows casting integers to pointers and vice versa, the results are implementation-defined and there's no guarantee that `int -> void* -> int` round-trips (although, a footnote in the standard says

> The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
>   be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.

so *probably* it will round-trip and work as intended in this case - but it would likely not work [only for values of small enough absolute value] if the size of a `void*` is smaller than that of the integer type [consider `long long -> void* -> long long` on 32-bit systems]).

The proper fix is to avoid the casting between integers and pointers,

```
void *serverThread(void *arg) {
    // ... check that arg isn't NULL
    int newsockfd = *(int *)arg;
    // ...
}
```

in `severThread`, cast the received pointer to a pointer of appropriate type, and read the pointed-to value, and in `main`

```
if// ...
int newsockfdd = whatever;
// ...
if (pthread_create(&threadID[i++], NULL, serverThread, &newsockfdd) != 0)
```

pass the address of `newsockfdd`.

One caveat: if `serverThread` is called from multiple places, the calls in all these places need to be fixed.

Comment: In main you suggest passing the address of a local variable as the parameter. This is a bug, if main exits before serverThread() executes, and the latter tries to dereference the address (which is no longer a valid address, since newsockfdd will be freed when main exits) your program will crash. Better to either intermediate cast, or pass the address of a static variable instead of a local (local) one.

Comment: Hmm, I had the impression that if `main` exits, it takes all `pthread_create`d threads with it (but it should join the spawned threads anyway).

Comment: I don't think that's guaranteed but I could be wrong. In any case though it's better safe than sorry; consider if the thread creation is done in a helper function called by main. Then the problem occurs regardless of whether main waits for children to exit. Just as a rule of thumb, it's best not to pass local addresses to other threads...